# Codeigniter View, how to pass two variables

Tags: codeigniter

My question is a little bit unprofessional but I'm a newbie in CodeIgniter looked so far in documentation and didn't found an answer.

Let say I have 2 table one for products and the other for special offers.

I want to view both table records in one page and the same view file.

I used to do it with smarty by assigning each array and loop through it in the template.

But in CodeIgniter

if I used the built-in template engine it's just like this

```
$this->parser->parse('template', $data);
```

And without template engine is like this

```
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

In both cases, it is only passing one variable to the view file.

How to pass multiple variables.

thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look into [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html).

Quoting:

```
$data = array(
               'title' => 'My Title',
               'heading' => 'My Heading',
               'message' => 'My Message'
          );

$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

In the view side, you'll be able to access the following variables:

```
echo($title);            // 'My Title'
echo($heading);          // 'My Heading'
echo($message);          // 'My Message'
```

Hope this gives you some clues for further research.

Edit #1 (reply to comment):

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$array2 = array('x', 'y', 'z');

$data['view_array1'] = $array1;
$data['view_array2'] = $array2;

$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

This will give you the following variables in the view:

```
$view_array1;    //  array('a', 'b', 'c')
$view_array2;    //  array('x', 'y', 'z')
```

Comment: thanks for your nice answer, but this is only one array I have 2 arrays from to different table.

Comment: You can still assign those arrays to a single variable in different indeces.

Answer (score 3):

In **Controller** you can make associative array like this

```
$data['Product'] = $product_array;
$data['Special_Offer'] = $special_offer_array;

$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

In **view** your variables would be $Product and $Special_Offer

Comment: thank you very much, so I have to loop through each "$data" array elements, thanks